# How do i pass input variable to a C++ class method invoked in many places based on user input?

Tags: c++, optimization

I have a file with multiple independent C-style functions defined in it ,wherein, each function instantiates a class and invokes a  method of that class with certain parameters.

I need to take input from the user on what function to call , and what parameter to send in that method.

Basically my requirement is as follows:

```
returnVal func1{
myClass obj;
obj.method(x,y);
}

returnVal func2{
myClass obj;
obj.method(x,y);
}

returnVal func3{
myClass obj;
obj.method(x,y);
}

//the value of y will need to change based on user selecting YES or NO
```

The obvious but tedious way is to put

```
if(userChoice == YES){
obj.method(x,y);
}
else{
obj.method(x);
}
```

inside every function , but the problem is i have too many such funcX , and so, i want to know if there is a simpler way, by using Macros or something, but Macros are substituted at compile time , so i am confused.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Functions can take parameters.

Comment: There are a number of different ways to achieve something like that, but it's hard to tell what your requirements are with those invalid functions you've given. You should post some real code which demonstrates your issue.

Comment: _"but the problem is i have too many such funcX"_ That's your real problem. Fix that.

Comment: @TartanLlama I cannot post the exact code here as it is bound by copyright laws. But the problem i am facing is exactly what i mentioned above. Could you post any way of achieving this out of the different ways you are talking about.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't modify or refactor the several occurrences of funcX , as all these functions carry drastically different implementations and the only common thing between them is this class method call, that i need to check n invoke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you use a switch/case structure to determine which function to call and what value of `y` to use?

```
returnType (func*)();    // Create a function pointer and use that
switch(userInput){
    case 0: 
        func = &func1;
        y = 5;
    case 1:
        func = &func2;
        y = 6;
}
```

To simplify the code inside each function, you could use a wrapper function:

```
void callObjMethod(userInput, MyClass obj, x, y){
    userInput == YES ? obj.method(x,y) : obj.method(x);
}
```

Or even just put the code from `callObjMethod` in each function depending on how complex the code is.